# Error encountered while deploying Community

Tags: lightning, community

While deploying community I am getting an error

> Network community_name- unknown exception has occurred

I have verified that name of the community is same in both the environments. Any solution?

Comment: Does that community exists in live?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Salesforce Community Deployment, by default, the Network API name of the community is set to the Community API name followed by `1`. So if your community API name is `My_Community` then the network name for the same community will be `My_Community1`.

But when you rename any community, that Network name format changes and `_C` is appended to the community name instead of `1`.

For eg., if you rename `My_Community` to `New_Community`, the network name will be changed to `New_Community_C`. That is why you can't find it while deploying.

The solution is to Rename your community in destination org to something else. Then rename it back to your desired name. Now you will be able to deploy it.

[Refer this.](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pLiFQAU)